# How to insert radio button into shiny UI based on another radio button input?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I am trying to create a basic userform in shiny based on which I need to perform some calculations. In order for me to do so, need to understand the material and shape of each product. There are 2 materials and each material has two shapes.

I would like to have one set of radio buttons for material.. and depending on which material the user chooses, the next set of radio buttons appear with the relevant shapes for that material.

There are two materials that the user can select - Gold or Silver.
The radio buttons for shape would appear based on the user input for the material. If they choose Silver, the shape should be either 'round' or 'square'. If they choose Gold, the shape should be either 'triangle' or 'rectangle'

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have tried using the insertUI function along with an if statement but have not been able to insert the buttons as required.

```
    library(shiny)

    library(shinydashboard)

    header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Calculator")

    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

      sidebarMenu(

id = "tabs",

menuItem("Main Menu", tabName = "main_menu", icon = icon("dashboard")))

body <- dashboardBody( 
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "main_menu",
            h2("Please select a material and shape"), 
            hr(), 
            radioButtons(inputId = "material",
                         label = "Material: ",
                         choices = c("Silver" = "silver", 
                                     "Gold" = "gold"))
    ))



    ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'This is my Page title', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')


    server <- function(input, output, session) { 



    }
```

The radio buttons for shape would appear based on the user input for the material. If they choose Silver, the shape should be either 'round' or 'square'. If they choose Gold, the shape should be either 'triangle' or 'rectangle'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `conditionalPanel()`.

NB: The condition is in JavaScript, so be careful if you are writing a different condition as there are ways it differs to R syntax.

Also note that this therefore creates two separate inputs (one for each silver and gold), so you will need to incorporate that into whatever your output is.

This would be your new `body`:

```
body <- dashboardBody( 
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "main_menu",
            h2("Please select a material and shape"), 
            hr(), 
            radioButtons(inputId = "material",
                         label = "Material: ",
                         choices = c("Silver" = "silver", 
                                     "Gold" = "gold")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.material == 'silver'", 
                             radioButtons("silver_shape",
                                          label = "Shape:", 
                                          choices = c("Round", "Square"))),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.material == 'gold'", 
                             radioButtons("gold_shape",
                                          label = "Shape:", 
                                          choices = c("Triangle", "Rectangle")))
    ))
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thank you for the help

Comment: As a follow up to this question, i was wondering if a radio button could have 2 inputs.. say i were to add another dimension - 'color' after shape.. is there a way that  radio buttons for shape appear only when to conditions are met i.e. "input.material == 'silver'" and "input.shape == 'round'"

Comment: Yes. So for e.g. you would have something like `"input.material == 'silver' & input.silver_shape == 'round'"` (note that this is in JS). However, for this specific example, as "round" is only a shape associated with silver, you could actually just make it conditional based on the `input.silver_shape`, as that will necessarily pass through the silver-only condition as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Megan! This works perfectly. Yes, i had tried the solution that you have suggested  i.e. using `input.silver_shape`. The reason why I could not use it is because if the user changes their preference from Silver to Gold, the radio buttons for the color still remain on the screen..